# How to set up a form to create several records on a has_many :through join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a form that creates a new exercise with muscle_groups that are primary and secondary to the exercise.

Here's the relevant part of the schema:

```
create_table "exercised_muscle_groups", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "muscle_group_id"
    t.integer "exercise_id"
    t.string  "used_as"
end

add_index "exercised_muscle_groups", ["exercise_id"], name: "index_exercised_muscle_groups_on_exercise_id", using: :btree
add_index "exercised_muscle_groups", ["muscle_group_id"], name: "index_exercised_muscle_groups_on_muscle_group_id", using: :btree

create_table "exercises", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "muscle_groups", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Here's what I have for the models:

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exercised_muscle_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :muscle_groups, through: :exercised_muscle_groups

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :muscle_groups
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercised_muscle_groups
end

class MuscleGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exercised_muscle_groups 
  has_many :exercises, through: :exercised_muscle_groups

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercised_muscle_groups
end

class ExercisedMuscleGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :muscle_group
end
```

Here's what I have so far for the controller actions for new and create:

```
def new
   @exercise = Exercise.new
   @exercise.exercised_muscle_groups.build
end

def create
   @exercise = Exercise.new(exercise_params)
   #exercise.save 
   #then loop through all muscle groups marked as primary and then create a record for each one with value of "primary" for used_as column
   #then loop through all muscle groups marked as secondary and then create a record for each one with value of "secondary" for used_as column
   #if all saves are successful, then redirect to show page for that exercise
   #if any save unsuccessful, then redirect to new page with error message
end
```

Here's what I have for the form in the view. I know it's wrong and it doesn't work.

```
<%=form_for(@exercise) do |exercise_form| %>
    <%= exercise_form.label :name %>
    <%= exercise_form.text_field :name, class: 'text_field' %><br>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <% exercise_form.fields_for :exercised_muscle_groups do |muscle_group_form| %>

        <%= muscle_group_form.label :primary %>
        </div>
          <% MuscleGroup.all.each do |muscle_group| %>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <span class="col-xs-3">
               <%= check_box_tag "exercise[muscle_group_ids][]", muscle_group.id %>
              </span>
              <span class="col-xs-3">
                <%= muscle_group.name %>
              </span>
          </div>
        <% end %>

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <%= muscle_group_form.label :secondary %>
      </div>
      <% MuscleGroup.all.each do |muscle_group| %>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <span class="col-xs-3">
               <%= check_box_tag "exercise[muscle_group_ids][]", muscle_group.id %>
              </span>
              <span class="col-xs-3">
                <%= muscle_group.name %>
              </span>
          </div>
      <% end %>

    <% end %>
  <%= exercise_form.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

How do I set up the form for the exercise and controller actions? Am I overcomplicating this? Is there an easier way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How is it failing? Provide more information regarding your "errors'..

Comment: It's not so much that I'm having errors as I don't really know how to set up the form and controller action for a has_many :through association with multiple records on the join table for one create action from one form.

Comment: @HoodieOnRails what happens if you use that form and submit data through it? Can you post the log to show what is entered into the DB. For a habtm association, the form looks good.